# Handsontable is showing all columns, virtual rendering is working only for rows

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I've got the last version of handsontable and now they are showing all my columns on the screen, for ex: I have 1000 cols and 1000 rows and table is showing 10 rows for my width and 1000 cols.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(el, {
  colWidths:30,
  colHeaders: true,
  data: data,
  minSpareRows: 1,
  stretchH: "all",
  variableRowHeights: false,
  height: 200,

  width: 200,
})
```

Comment: Has this been fixed in the newer versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version fixed this. Check this [link](http://handsontable.com/demo/scroll.html).